# Finding random index

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, I have created an array of 15 random integers and I have found the minimum and maximum value. I now need to concatenate the index of the maximum and minimum value.

```
package homework7;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author a
 */
public class Homework7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Name and Homework Number 
        System.out.println("A" + " \nHomework 7");

        int[] numbers = new int[15];
        //Generates 15 Random Numbers in the range 1 - 1000
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 - 1);
        }//end for loop
        System.out.println("\nContents of the Array:\n" + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        // Calling getMax() method for getting max value
        int max = getMax(numbers);
        System.out.println("\nMaximum Value " + max + " is located at index ");

        // Calling getMin() method for getting min value
        int min = getMin(numbers);
        System.out.println("Minimum Value " + min + " is located at index ");

    }

    // Method for getting the maximum value
    public static int getMax(int[] inputArray) {
        int maxValue = inputArray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = inputArray[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    // Method for getting the minimum value
    public static int getMin(int[] inputArray) {
        int minValue = inputArray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = inputArray[i];
            }
        }
        return minValue;

    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: A way to find the index of the minimum and maximum values of this random array

Comment: Return the index from your `getMin` and `getMax` methods, then you can print `minIndex` and `numbers[minIndex]`.

Comment: Please read [Open letter to students with homework problems](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Your random statement doesn't do what your comment says (it will generate values in the range -1 to 998). Use Random.nextInt(1000) + 1.

Comment: If you dont want to help just dont respond. Thank you very much, im not asking anyone to do my homework im asking for some advice.

Comment: Thank you for your advice teppic

Answer (score 0):

add  a variable  to  mark  the `i` ,  when  you get the  new min/max value in if block mark the `i` .

Answer (score 0):

There may be various ways to solve, below are possible solutions I can think of:

- Naive way would be to add more functions to scan over the array to return the index of min and max value of the array (this would be an extra scan and more work).
- Other way can be adding of global variables to track the index where max and min occurred.
- Also, as a suggestion you could update min and max in single function by merging your two functions and updating min and max of array as global variables as well. This will do everything on one scan of the array.