# output the smallest integer in an array, and the index of it

Tags: java

I've been coding this program but I've got a little bit stuck and would like some advice. This is what I've got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallestInArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        input(array);
        output(array);
    }

    public static void input(int[] array)
    {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = kybd.nextInt();
        }
    }


    public static int findSmallest(int[] array, int first)
    {
        int smallestPos = first;
        for (int i = first + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[smallestPos]) {
                smallestPos = i;
            }
        }
        return smallestPos;
    }

    public static void output(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Everything is fine other than the `findSmallest` method, as I'd like to output the smallest value and the index of it, but I'm not quite sure what to pass as the parameters in the main method?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: Well for example if I have         System.out.println(findSmallest()); I have no idea what to pass in as parameters for it to output the smallest value and the index of it

Comment: Why did you add the `first` parameter? Remove it. Or call with value `0`.

Comment: Yourproblems is related with return two values ?

Comment: What about the second parameter, what code should I use to call it?

Comment: Discussion at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950675/finding-random-index/40951118#40951118 might help.

Comment: @Luke I already told you what code to use for second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the refactored code which gets you both the value and index of smallest element in the array.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class SmallestInArray
{
    int index_of_smallest_element;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        input(array);
        SmallestInArray smallestInArray = new SmallestInArray();
        System.out.printf("Smallest Value:%d corresponding Index:%d\n",smallestInArray.findSmallest(array), smallestInArray.index_of_smallest_element);
        output(array);
    }

    public static void input(int[] array)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 10 integers: ");
        try (Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = kybd.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public int findSmallest(int[] array)
    {
        int smallestValue = array[0];
        index_of_smallest_element = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (smallestValue > array[i]) // it doesn't accounts for duplicate values
            {
                smallestValue = array[i];
                index_of_smallest_element = i;
            }
        }
        return smallestValue;
    }

    public static void output(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + "  ");
        }
    }}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] array = new int[10]; 
        input(array);
        output(array);

        int smallestPos = findSmallest(array, 0 /* P.S. this parameter seem to be useless */);
        int smallestVal = array[smallestPos];
        // output the two
    }
```